# last inserted id/latest inserted id function codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Codes:

View

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo form_open('samplecontroller/sample'); ?>
<input type="text" name="samplename"/> 
<input type="submit" value="go"/> 
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
<?php

Class samplecontroller extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct() 
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Sample_insert');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('sample.php');

    }

    function show($data)
    {
        $this->load->view('sampleresult',$data);
    }

    function sample()
    {
            if($result = $this->Sample_insert->insert_into_sample())
            {
             $this->show($result);
            }

    }
}
?>
```

Model

```
<?php
Class Sample_insert extends CI_Model
{
    function insert_into_sample()
    {
        $sample = array(
            'samplename' => $this->input->post('samplename'),
            );      

        $this->db->insert('sample', $sample);

        $latest_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        return $latest_id;
    }
}
?>
```

The flow is that, i have 2 views. The other one contains only 1 text input, after which goes to controller then controller passes it on to model then model gets the value within the text input then inserts to my sample table.

The sample table has 2 columns, id(PK,AI) and name

after it inserts, on my model. i added a line, return $latest_id. Then passes goes back to my controller then passes it off to another view that only has

```
print_r($data);
```

After all that, it displays an error.

> Message: Undefined variable: data

Im not sure where the flow went wrong or if i made a syntax mistake. If someone knows/expert on insert_id(), could you pin point where exactly i am wrong? anyways, ive made my research and been getting results on the web how buggy insert_id is. Im not sure if its true or not but ive been redirected mostly to forums wherein insert_id returns null and some say its a bug. Im hoping it isnt.

Comment: where are you getting error in controller or view?

Comment: The view, apparently, the variable $data from the model passed onto the controller then to the view.

Would you care to check on how i returned the variable from there and tell me if i did something wrong, perhaps the function was used wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, You have to do some changes in your controller.

```
function show($data)
    {
        $this->load->view('sampleresult',array("data"=>$data));
    }
```

You can get inserted id in view in the name of `$data`.

For ex:

```
echo $data;
```

**Edit:** As per your comment in answer, For multiple row insert in model, add below code

```
$id_arr = array();
foreach($sample_data as $sample)
{

   $this->db->insert('sample', $sample);
   $id_arr[] = $this->db->insert_id();
}
return $id_arr;
```

Now in your view, you will get ids in $data

```
foreach($data as $id)
{
   echo $id;
}
```

Comment: Does this work if i loop and insert 5 rows. For example i have an auto increment id. so i should expect it to be, 0,1,2,3,4 right?

Comment: Then you have to store Ids in an array in your model. Let me update my answer

Comment: You're a great help. Btw one last question,

Why do i have to pass the variable $data as an array to the view?
this part, array("data"=>$data))

Comment: CI will extract the array values with name of it's key name in view file. So we need to pass it as array only.

Comment: You mean an associative array right?

like, foreach($data as $key=>$value)

Comment: yes. CI will do it. So we will get the variable in the name of $key